# Can a Facebook object have two URLs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm creating an "object" via Facebook's Open Graph.  Obviously it's assigned a unique URL within my application (e.g. www.myapp.com/something/hash), and I'm injecting the relevant OG meta tags.  All fine, and I can then "attach" a "Like" button and Facebook comments.

However those user-created objects are generated from within a Facebook application - which happens to "live" under the same domain (e.g. www.myapp.com/fb) and that object has its own page within the Facebook application (e.g. www.myapp.com/fb/something/hash)

Thus, that same object has effectively two unique URLs.  The "external" one is the one I use to identify it, but I also want to have a "Like" button and Facebook comments on that page.  It doesn't seem to accept a URL in, say, the fb-like DIV and corresponding og:url meta tag that doesn't match the URl it's housed on.

Is there any way around this - or do I need to do something like a redirect when calling the page from within the Facebook app, or some sort of clever template switching?

Comment: Lukas, do you make seperate pages for each object? Or do you do them dynamically? (the action calling url)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `og:url` meta tag value for *both* URLs to the one URL you want to be the “actual” URL of the object.